# Mpld3 styling issue when saving to html

Tags: python, html, matplotlib, jupyter, mpld3

When I save the plot to html, the styling is different to what it shows within Jupyter.  Following image is direct from jupyter and is exactly how I want it:   [plot from jupyter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q234m.png)

The following image is what is saved by the mpld3 code:  [plot from mpld3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0QtTm.png)

The text is changed to Times New Roman, the y-axis is not in scientific notation so it covers the y-axis label, the text is too small etc.

How do I get mpld3 to save to html exactly as it displays in jupyter?

```
#  Global imports
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure
import mpld3

x = []
y = []
fig = figure(figsize=(12, 9))
ax = fig.gca()
for key, val in passenger_km_dict.items():
    x.append(int(key))
    y.append(int(val) * 1000000)
#print(x)
#print(y)
ax.plot(x, y)
ax.set_xlabel('Year')  # Set some labels
ax.set_ylabel('Kilometres (1 ** 11)')
ax.set_title('Passenger Car Kilometres per Year from 1970 through 2017')
mpld3.save_html(fig,'Graphics\plot_passenger_km_per_year.html', template_type='simple')
#mpld3.show(fig)
```

Thanks!

Comment: The figure generated by matplotlib in jupyter has little to nothing to do with the figure generated by mpld3 in html. It may hence be more useful to ask three questions: How do I change the font of a mpld3 figure? How do I use scientific notation on mpld3 figures? How do I change the position of the y label of a mpld3 figure?

Comment: Yeah, well that's the issue.  matplotlib outputs the plot perfectly.  And mpld3 does not.  It's a glaring issue with mpld3 programming and I'm asking if anyone knows how to fix it or get around.  I don't have the patience to change 15 or so parameters to make it the same.  Is there, for example, a way to export matplotlib output into html, or something else so I can embed the object into an iframe?  For clarity, this plot is derived from data that will be updated every year.  So the code will be run yearly with a new dataset, so the plot must change also.  Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Yes, answering my own question...

I think I solved it by using matplotlib.pyplot.savefig(*args)

```
plt.savefig('Graphics\plot_passenger_km_per_year_matplotlib.jpg')
```